# How can I modify this closed-connection regex to cover multi-line invalid user entries

Tags: python, regex, ssh

I need a regex string to give to denyhosts config for filtering invalid ssh login attempts to my remote server.

Here is the regex that I am using currently:

```
USERDEF_FAILED_ENTRY_REGEX=.*sshd.* Connection closed by .* (?P<host>\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}) port \d{1,5} \[preauth\]
```

It filters this kind of logs perfectly:

```
sshd[4086]: Connection closed by authenticating user root 141.98.10.172 port 50610 [preauth]
```

and gets 141.98.10.172 within text.

However I need to filter below ones too in same regex:

```
sshd[4260]: Disconnected from authenticating user root 128.199.82.240 port 46392 [preauth]
sshd[4262]: Invalid user admin12 from 43.134.178.78 port 36540
```

How can I do this in one regex?

Answer (score 3):

You can use this regex:
.*sshd.* \S+ .* (?P\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}) (port \d{1,5} [preauth]|port \d{1,5})

You can verify the regex on https://regex101.com/.

Your regex had constant strings "**Connection closed by**" which can be replaced by **\S+** to cater multiple string messages.

Third log line didn't end on "**preauth**" so here we needed an "OR |" in regex to handle the log lines that do not ends with "**preauth**"

Comment: Great, so meaningful, but i will check it if it will parse valid login attempts too or not. Thank you

Comment: Unfortunately it also filters valid authantications too but your idea was great so i vote up, thank you

Answer (score 1):

This regex solves my problem, filters invalid login attempts and not catches valid login attempts

```
.*sshd.* (?:Disconnected from authenticating user root|Invalid .*|closed by .*) (?P<host>\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}) port \d{1,5}
```

like these ones:

```
# Valid attempts, not filtering
sshd[1152]: Received disconnect from 192.168.1.50 port 51385:11: disconnected by user
sshd[1152]: Disconnected from user xmms 192.168.1.50 port 51385
sshd[1201]: Accepted publickey for xmms from 192.168.1.50 port 51512 ssh2: RSA SHA256:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

# Invalid attempts, filtering
sshd[4260]: Disconnected from authenticating user root 128.199.82.240 port 46392 [preauth]
sshd[4262]: Invalid user admin12 from 43.134.178.78 port 36540
sshd[4086]: Connection closed by authenticating user root 141.98.10.172 port 50610 [preauth]
```

Thank you @Shehroz Chishty for the idea

https://stackoverflow.com/a/76129137/617648